# Memory address emulation or mocking

Tags: c, memory, arm, embedded

Ive seen few other posts in stack, but none really answered my question. 
Is it possible to emulate or somehow map or have a driver that emulates specific memory addresses that otherwise dont exist on host machine?

Im looking at piece of embedded code that i need to troubleshoot, but its reading values from memory  space that doesn't exist on my pc. I could change this one instance of address, but those nonexistent  addressees are all over the place on the code, so changing them all just isn't practical.

Comment: If you have a program that is accessing addresses of anything other than objects declared by the program (which necessarily do exist), then to the extent that the behavior is meaningful at all, its effect is specific to the combination of C implementation and especially the hardware on which it runs.  To run such code elsewhere, you probably need a virtual machine or similar whole-machine emulator.  These exist for many targets.  It is unlikely that you will find any kind of lighter-weight driver or emulator that would just paper over the invalid memory accesses, however.

Comment: on Windows you could try using `VirtualAlloc`, to allocate at a specific address

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible to make the code run for testing purposes, but how easy it would be depends on two things: How exactly is the code referencing the addresses and what are the memory accesses supposed to do?

Generally speaking, you could write a library to mock the other hardware. Writing such a library could be anything between easy and difficult, depending on what those accesses are supposed to do. In an easy case, the accesses wouldn't affect each other in a way that would need to be emulated. In a more difficult case, you might need some kind of a state machine to track what is going on. In a medium case, there might be a need to remember some values from earlier accesses but no need for a more complex state machine.

Writing a library may not be enough, though. You would also need to make the code that you are troubleshooting use that library. In practice, the code needs to call functions offered by the library. If the memory accesses are already done via some function calls, you could simply have your own versions of those functions in your library. Otherwise, more effort is needed.

If accesses are not via function calls but by directly referencing the addresses, one solution might be to try writing regular expressions to match the references. If you had regular expressions matching all or at least most of them, you could use them and some tool like sed to replace the references with function calls more or less automatically.